# Updating rows in Android SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using SQlite in my Android app and the task is - how can I update all the rows in one table? 
I have a 1st column with name "cl_id" (integer numbers 1-2-3-4..) and after deleting some rows, I wan't to make a cycle to fill this 1st column with a new values to keep them in right order.

I was trying to execute:

```
        data.put("cl_id",index);
        db.update("mdb_table_contactList", data, null, null);
```

but it's updates all the values in the first column :(

Comment: the data that are updated into the database..how do you get it, Are you storing the data in ArrayList first and passing it to the database?  And I believe the data gets updated only on the first row.

Comment: In my db I have only 2 columns: cl_id - just ID , one by one, and phone_id - it's a ID of the contact in the Phone DB (like a link to get it fast). When in my Fragment I'm showing contacts in order according to cl_id, with data according to the link in phone_ID field. Something like this..

Comment: Why would you want to change the ID values? If they change, they don't actually identify the rows.

Answer (score 0):

To update the field in specific row, try this;

```
ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
data.put("cl_id",index);
db.update("mdb_table_contactList", data, "id="+_id, null);
db.close();
```

It's good practice to have a primary key for each row data.
Here _id would be your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

"just give rowId and type of data that is going to be update in ContentValues."

public void updateStatus(String id , int status){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

data.put("status", status);

db.update(TableName, data, "columnName" + " = "+id , null);

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this it must work

```
void updateDatail(String id) {
         ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
         data.put("cl_id",index);
         db.update("mdb_table_contactList", data, "id=?", new String[]{id});
         db.close();
}
```